# Parsing MPEG21 XML file in R

Tags: xml, r

I'm trying to parse this [MPEG21 XML file](http://resolver.kb.nl/resolve?urn=ddd:010168412:mpeg21), but I'm having some problems with it.
Since reading it from its URL didn't work, I downloaded the file and read the local copy:

```
ns <- "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"
file <-  "ddd:010168412.xml"

xml.content<- xmlTreeParse(file)
xml.top <- xmlRoot(xml.content)
```

Now, what I need is to extract for every ID (for example ddd:010168412:mpeg21:a0003) as in

```
<didl:Component dc:identifier="ddd:010168412:mpeg21:a0003:zoning">
```

the IDs of the TextBlocks that belong to it, for example:

```
<dcx:TextBlock ID="P1_TB00019"/>
<dcx:TextBlock ID="P1_TB00020"/>
<dcx:TextBlock ID="P1_TB00021"/>
<dcx:TextBlock ID="P1_TB00022"/>
<dcx:TextBlock ID="P1_TB00023"/>
```

However, none of my attempts to extract anything from the tree works, for example this returns nothing, not even an error:

```
x <- sapply(getNodeSet(xml.top, "//responseDate"), xmlValue)
```

I'm getting the impression that I'm overlooking something really basic. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the undeclared namespace in the XML document's root tag where the special alias `xmlns` does not have a prefix denoted with colon:

```
xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/"
```

As a result, you need to declare a prefix to the namespace and use it in each XPath call including getNodeSet and/or xpathSApply:

```
namespaces <- c(ns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/")

x <- sapply(getNodeSet(file, "//ns:responseDate", namespaces), xmlValue)
x
# [1] "2016-05-19T03:42:59.576Z"

# ALTERNATIVE
x <- xpathSApply(file, "//ns:responseDate", xmlValue, namespaces = namespaces)
x
# [1] "2016-05-19T03:42:59.576Z"
```

You can also register multiple namespaces:

```
namespaces <- c(ns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/",
                dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
                dcx="http://krait.kb.nl/coop/tel/handbook/telterms.html")

y <- xpathSApply(file, "//dcx:TextBlock", xmlGetAttr, "ID",
                 namespaces = namespaces)
head(y)
# [1] "P1_TB00012" "P1_TB00013" "P1_TB00014" "P1_TB00015" "P1_TB00016"
# [6] "P1_TB00017"
```